# colourful characters to draw in the media

Tags: meaning

Source: [Poroshenko faces judgement day as Ukraine votes without rebel east](http://news.yahoo.com/poroshenko-faces-judgement-day-ukraine-votes-without-rebel-170452829.html)

Example:

> The demoralised mood of voters has been picked up by an astonishing 132 parties that use boastful slogans and **colourful characters to draw in the media** and prompt endless TV debates.

What exactly are they saying? What do they mean by *draw colorful characters in the media*?

Comment: I think that here *the [attention of the] media* is getting *drawn* - not *the colorful characters*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, [***draw***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/draw) means:

> 1b) to pull in (a dragnet, etc.)
>
> The demoralised mood of voters has been picked up by an astonishing 132 parties that use boastful slogans and colourful characters to **pull in** the media and prompt endless TV debates.

meaning using colourful characters to attract the media and get them involved in the activity (the debates).